# css transition out of scale-in-hor-center. Right now it just drops out instead of animation

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

Ok so i know a decent amount about CSS, web design, etc. But i have been scratching my head and banging my fists for the last 2 hours trying to figure this one out. Either 13hrs straight of web design today has fried my brain and the answer should be obvious, or the solution is outside of my current knowledge.

So i have setup a simple link, and added an icon in the :before class. the icon is positioned underneath the text, and is transparent during no activity. Once the user hovers over the link, the icon will appear with the scale-in-hor-center animation. My issue is that when the users mouse leaves the link, instead of a smooth transition back out, it is just a sharp abrupt drop off. Ive tried everything i can think of, someone please halp!!!

Here is my current code:

```
    .link-effect {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}

.link-effect:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   font-weight: 900;
   content: "\f141";
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   color: transparent;
}
.link-effect:hover:before {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
   font-weight: 900;
   content: "\f141";
   color: #000000;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-animation: scale-in-hor-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
   animation: scale-in-hor-center 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-hor-center {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   100% {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }
}

@keyframes scale-in-hor-center {
   0% {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      opacity: 1;
   }

   100% {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload a working demo if possible ?

Comment: As your animation is rather simple, you may simply use a [CSS Transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).